# How to chain futures in a non-blocking manner? That is, how to use one future as an input in another future without blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

Using the below example, how can `future2` use the result of `future1` once `future1` is complete (without blocking `future3` from being submitted)?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def wait(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return seconds

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()

s = time.time()
future1 = pool.submit(wait, 5)
future2 = pool.submit(wait, future1.result())
future3 = pool.submit(wait, 10)

time_taken = time.time() - s
print(time_taken)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is achievable by carefully crafting a callback to submit the second operation after the first one has completed. Sadly, it is not possible to pass an arbitrary future to `pool.submit` so an extra step is required to bind the two futures together.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import concurrent.futures

def copy_future_state(source, destination):
    if source.cancelled():
        destination.cancel()
    if not destination.set_running_or_notify_cancel():
        return
    exception = source.exception()
    if exception is not None:
        destination.set_exception(exception)
    else:
        result = source.result()
        destination.set_result(result)


def chain(pool, future, fn):
    result = concurrent.futures.Future()

    def callback(_):
        try:
            temp = pool.submit(fn, future.result())
            copy = lambda _: copy_future_state(temp, result)
            temp.add_done_callback(copy)
        except:
            result.cancel()
            raise

    future.add_done_callback(callback)
    return result
```

Note that `copy_future_state` is a slightly modified version of [asyncio.futures._set_concurrent_future_state](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L351-L363).

Usage:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def wait(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return seconds

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
future1 = pool.submit(wait, 5)
future2 = chain(pool, future1, wait)
future3 = pool.submit(wait, 10)
```