# Convert a future object to a data form

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to make async call using futures and all the responses that i'm getting from future method is <class. concurrent.futures._base.Future> type.
How can i apply json.loads and convert these objects to decipher their original returned content?

```
urls= ['google.com', 'xyz.com' ]
with FutureSession() as Session:
   futures= [session.get(url) for url in urls]
   for future in futures:
     jsonrespon= json.loads(future.text) # this is my blockage. How to interpret future object to json or other data form
     future.result()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python futures and tuple unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334728/python-futures-and-tuple-unpacking)

Comment: thanks for the head up! but the method isn't clear. how can you practically have a json.lods to decode the future object.